# Uzbek citizen with Kazakh residence permit entering USA

Tags: visas, usa, uzbek-citizens

I`m a citizen of Uzbekistan, and a holder of permanent residence permit of Kazakhstan. Do I need when entering the USA internal exit visa of Uzbekistan (OVIR), the travel visa to the USA is available, issued by the Embassy of USA in Kazakhstan.

Comment: Sorry, it's a little hard to understand. Are you trying to get into the US as a visitor? You're applying from in Kazakhstan (Almaty?)?

Answer (score 3):

Legally speaking, **yes**, you would need a valid exit visa. [Official source](http://lex.uz/Pages/GetAct.aspx?lact_id=1945475):

> 7. В соответствии с законодательством граждане Республики Узбекистан, выехавшие на временное жительство (в служебную командировку, на учебу, работу по контракту и т. д.), в страны, для въезда в которые не требуется оформление въездных виз, в случаях необходимости выезда в третью страну, для въезда в которую по законодательству Республики Узбекистан требуется оформление въездных виз, должны обращаться в консульские учреждения Республики Узбекистан за рубежом с заявлением об оформлении стикера для выезда в эту страну (пункт 5 раздела II Порядка въезда-выезда граждан). Несоблюдение данного порядка следует расценивать как незаконный выезд за границу, влекущий уголовную ответственность.

My own rough translation:

> In accordance with Uzbekistan law, persons leaving the country for a temporary residence (business, employment, study, etc.) in a country which does not require the posession of a valid exit visa must request a new exit visa when visiting a country which requires an exit visa. Failing to fulfill this responsibility is a violation punishable by criminal law.

Kazakhstan is a country which does not require an exit visa and the USA is a country which does. Therefore you need a valid OVIR sticker. Anecdotal confirmation can also be found on [Uzbekistani forums](http://www.fromuz.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=34475).

Note that Kazakh immigration is unlikely to allow you to leave the country, as the CIS treaty obliges them to check for exit visas in Uzbek passports. However the US authorities would have no issue with letting you enter the country, as long as your US visa is valid.

Comment: The question is whether or not you will need one when entering the US.

Comment: @Karlson I think its reasonable to answer outside the scope as its illegal for Inna to visit the US without the exit visa.

Comment: I am thinking refugees...  But being a resident of Kazakhstan the laws of Kazakhstan may apply more to the point then Uzbekistan but even then why would a US CBP officer care whether or not you had permission to leave the country unless you're a fugitive somewhere and law enforcement requested to have you detained.

Comment: Kazakhstan won't allow Inna to leave the country, at least they're not supposed to officially.

Comment: @Karlson there are agreements signed between Uzbekistan and CIS countries which state that CIS authorities must check the validity of passports in accordance to national law before letting the person leave. [Here's one signed with Russia](http://www.mid.ru/bdomp/spd_md.nsf/0/CB4BF8EAEA3738F143257E4C00246E4F), as an example (see article 3).

Comment: The US does not have exit visas.

Comment: @MichaelHampton US policies only apply if you're allowed to leave the country, which Inna would not be permitted (at least officially).

Answer (score 0):

When you arrive at the US border no-one really cares whether or not you had permission to leave your country of origin or country of residence.

So the permission to leave the country of Uzbekistan is only applicable to Uzbekistan unless a treaty exists between the countries to check for such visas which I wasn't able to find between Uzbekistan and US.

Further.  If you are a resident of Kazakhstan doesn't this mean that you already have a visa to leave Uzbekistan?